# Errors implementing quicksort

Tags: java

My code is below. It is a sorting method included in a project instead of bubblesort for efficiency of code. My problem is that I keep getting errors which are:

`array required, but java.util.List<Inpatient> found`

&

`QuickSort(java.util.List<Inpatient>,int,int) in UtilitiesInpatient cannot be applied to (int,int)`

I've tried doing some research but a lot of algorithms vary a lot depending on string or integer sorting and also, research on the errors themselves were highly unhelpful. Many thanks for any help or tips!

```
    public void QuickSort (List<Inpatient> inpatientArrayListIn, int first, int last) 
    {

        // Quick Sort

        List<Inpatient> pivotValue = new ArrayList<Inpatient>();
        List<Inpatient> lowerPointerValue = new ArrayList<Inpatient>();
        List<Inpatient> upperPointerValue = new ArrayList<Inpatient>();

        int pivotIndex = first;
        Inpatient tempPatient = (inpatientArrayListIn.get(pivotIndex));
        String pivot = tempPatient.getSurname();
        int upperPointer = first;
        int lowerPointer = last;

        while (upperPointer < lowerPointer) {


            while ((inpatientArrayListIn.get(upperPointer).getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(pivot) <= 0) && (upperPointer < last)) {

                upperPointer++;

            }


            while (((inpatientArrayListIn.get(lowerPointer).getSurname()).compareToIgnoreCase(pivot) > 0) && (lowerPointer > first)){

                lowerPointer--;

            }

            if (upperPointer < lowerPointer) {

                for (int i = 0; i <= inpatientArrayListIn.size(); i++) {

                    upperPointerValue[i] = ((inpatientArrayListIn.get(upperPointer)));
                    lowerPointerValue[i] = ((inpatientArrayListIn.get(lowerPointer)));

                }

              /*  defaultTable.removeRow (upperPointer);
                defaultTable.insertRow (upperPointer, lowerPointerValue);
                defaultTable.removeRow (lowerPointer);
                defaultTable.insertRow (lowerPointer, upperPointerValue);
                */
                ++upperPointer;
                --lowerPointer;

            }

        }

        if ((inpatientArrayListIn.get(lowerPointer).getSurname()).compareTo(pivot) < 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= inpatientArrayListIn.size(); i++) {

                pivotValue[i] = inpatientArrayListIn.get(pivotIndex);
                lowerPointerValue[i] = (inpatientArrayListIn.get(lowerPointer));

            }
            /*
            defaultTable.removeRow (pivotIndex);
            defaultTable.insertRow (pivotIndex, lowerPointerValue);
            defaultTable.removeRow (lowerPointer);
            defaultTable.insertRow (lowerPointer, pivotValue);
            */
        }

        // Value in lowerPointer is now the pivot

        if (first < (lowerPointer-1)) 
        {

            QuickSort (first, (lowerPointer-1));

        }

        if ((lowerPointer+1) < last) 
        {

            QuickSort ((lowerPointer+1), last);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post the complete exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Is this a complier error or a runtime exception that occurs?

Comment: I see different method signatures for QuickSort in your code?  Did you intend for that?  If so, can you post those as well

Comment: It is a compiler error... Also, this is my code implemented on sample code sent by my teacher... So to be honest, I can't judge exactly what she intended.

Answer (score 0):

In this portion:

```
    if (first < (lowerPointer-1)) 
    {

        QuickSort (first, (lowerPointer-1));

    }

    if ((lowerPointer+1) < last) 
    {

        QuickSort ((lowerPointer+1), last);

    }
```

You are missing the first argument, `List<Inpatient> inpatientArrayListIn`, exactly as the error message describes. Also, you are trying to use `List` as an array, as in:

```
upperPointerValue[i] = ((inpatientArrayListIn.get(upperPointer)));
```

If we look at the documentation for [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), the method you want is `set(int index, E element)`, so the above would be:

```
upperPointerValue.set(i, inpatientArrayListIn.get(upperPointer));
```

There really is not much more one can say about the problems you are facing that the compiler isn't already telling you.

Comment: I also make no claims about the validity of the logic in your program, as it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: The reason I was confused mostly about the second one is because by teacher taught me that arrays, are found within Lists... so it makes more sense for me to use Lists the way I did... So to be honest, that particular error still confuses me as I do not know with what I am supposed to replace that part with... I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if i seem to be asking stupid questions...

Comment: Also, my code is much much larger, this is a just a small portion, one method. The method was sent to me by my teacher and I fixed the bugs I could. If my teacher can't fix it I don't know how I should know how to.